# Is it possible to create a columnfamily which contains normal column as well as super column?

Tags: database-design, cassandra, hector

I am looking for a column family in which i can add both super columns and normal columns like in the example below

```
keyspace1{
      :rowid1 AND its associated column field
      :rowid2 with a Super Column 
}
```

is it possible? if yes plz suggest
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question is no it's not possible. You can't mix standard and super columns in a single column family. It's better if you avoid super column as it is being deprecated over time.

However I did recently see an article on the Cassandra user group identifying some advantages of super column families.

Answer (score 4):

I know I'm not directly answering your question, but I think you should reconsider using SuperColumns in your data model.

I'm quoting from an [article](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/schema-in-cassandra-1-1) posted by DataStax recently (February 15, 2012):

> SuperColumns were an early attempt at providing the same kinds of denormalization tools discussed above. They have important limitations (e.g., reading any subcolumn from a SuperColumn pulls the entire SuperColumn into memory) and will eventually be replaced by a composite column implementation with the same API. So if you have an application using SuperColumns, you don’t need to rewrite anything, but if you are starting fresh, you should use the more flexible approach described above.

I think it's worth for you to look at, [here](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/introduction-to-composite-columns-part-1) might be a nice place to start.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Adi. It is really helpful. I hope i can now proceed smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot mix standard and super columns within the same column family.  When you create a column family, you must specify whether it is a standard column family or a super column family.  However, you can achieve the same effect by using composite columns (which are recommended over super columns).